# Create csv file of all disabled AD users with mailboxes Output information from multiple cmdlets in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I am trying to gather some information on disabled user accounts that have mailboxes. I am specifically looking for just user mailboxes not shared mailboxes.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox'}
```

$date = get-date -f "MMddyyyy_HHmm"
$Disabled = @()

Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
if((Get-ADUser -Identity $Mailbox.SamAccountName).Enabled -eq $False){
$Disabled += Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox.SamAccountName | Select -Property DisplayName,TotalItemSize
}
}
$Disabled | Sort DisplayName | Export-Csv -Path "%path%\DisabledADUsersWithMailbox_$date`.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Additionally what I would like to collect is the users Title, Manager, LastlogonDate all of which can be found using Get-Aduser. I am unsure how I go about collecting the information from both cmdlets and then exporting it all to csv. I have read that I may need to create a custom object. I am struggling with setting that up in this script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following lines should give you what you want, can't verify it as I have no exchange running here.

```
$date = get-date -f "MMddyyyy_HHmm" 

$Disabled = @(
    Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) { 
        $adUser = get-aduser -Identity $Mailbox.SamAccountName -Properties enabled,manager,title,lastlogontimestamp
        If ($adUser.Enabled -eq $False){
            $mailStats = Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox.SamAccountName 
            $attrsht = [ordered]@{
                displayname=$mailstats.displayname
                totalitemsize=$mailStats.totalitemsize
                samaccountname=$aduser.samaccountname
                enabled=$aduser.enabled
                manager=$aduser.manager
                title=$aduser.title
                lastlogontimestamp=[datetime]::FromFileTime($aduser.lastlogontimestamp)
            }
            new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
        }
    }
)
 
$Disabled | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-Csv -Path "%path%\DisabledADUsersWithMailbox_$date`.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Avoid adding elements to an array by using +=. It is slow, alternatively take a look at generic array lists.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your updated Script does what I need. Is there anyway to format the output in the csv file so that Displayname is first? Or possible to change order of the columns? Also can you explain what lastlogontimestamp=[datetime]::FromFileTime($aduser.lastlogontimestamp) is doing?

Comment: I updated the code... the hashtable is now in order ([ordered])... [datetime]::FromFileTime() converts the original format to a human readable string

Comment: Can't thank you enough for your help with getting this done!